# Stuck on a probability problem/Expectation of coin toss

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

I'm stuck on the following problem that is due for tomorrow:

> We're flipping 1 coin indefinitely. $X$ is a random variable that count the amount of coin tosses.
>   What is the expectation of the number of coin toss until we have the following sequence: THH (T: tail, H: head)

We know that TTT has an expectation of 14.

Edit: Someone told me that

$E[X]= 3 + P[X>3]E[X].$

$P[X>3]=(1 - (1/8))$

$E[X]=24$

But I have now idea how to get to the last step?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. If you flip a coin indefinitely, it seems impossible you will wind up with exactly three coin flips. You will have an infinite number of coin flips. Do you mean you want to know the expected number of coin flips required before you wind up with consecutive coin flips in the pattern you seek?

Comment: Yes that's what i meant. Sorry

Comment: TTT is not "special". It is just a pattern. What makes THH different? In other words, apply the same method to computing the expectation for THH as you did for computing the expectation for TTT. Why would it be anything other than 14?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Presumably because the coin is not fair. But of course the FFF does not help.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe A reason the expectation for THH is a lot less than 14 is that in a long string of heads and tails, TTT can overlap itself a lot (and so can the equally special HHH) while THH cannot.  THT can overlap itself a bit, and so has an intermediate expectation

Comment: @Henry since you are looking for the first time that happens, overlaps seem less important. I haven't really thought about the problem, though, so perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @user - You can believe what you want, but if you do the calculations you will find HHH and TTT have the longest expected time (14), HTH and THT the next longest and the other four the shortest.  Then to really confuse things with the four patterns with the the same short expected times for first appearance, if you look out for two patterns and which arrives first, THH is three times as likely to arrive first as HHT, while HHT is twice as likely to arrive first as HTT, but HTT is three times as likely to arrive first as TTH, and TTH is twice as likely to arrive first as THH, i.e. a cycle

Comment: @Henry is correct, and InterstellarProbe and user are mistaken; further, almagest's suggestion that the coin is unfair is probably incorrect. This is a famous problem related to Penney's Game (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game); the wait time for any 3-letter sequence ranges from 8 to 14 depending on the sequence (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2685403).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Explanation of why different sequences would be different: if you are chasing the sequence TTT, and see two T's, then an occurrence of H resets you back to having nothing. But if you are chasing TTH, and you see two T's, then a third occurrence of T does NOT reset you back to nothing; you're still just one letter away from winning.

Comment: @RoyalValue Regarding the three equations in your edit: as I mentioned in a previous comment, 14 is the longest result for a three-letter sequence in coin flips (note: that claim isn't *obvious* per se, but it's true). Hence, that answer that someone told you is incorrect. The first equation is incorrect; the middle one is correct, and the last one inherits the mistake of the first equation.

Comment: What makes TTT different from THH (and from THT) is that THH has no proper initial substrings that equal a final substring, whereas, THT has one such substring (i.e. T) and TTT has two such substrings (T and TT). The overlapping substrings imply that some occurrences of the desired string in a long sequence don't "count" since they overlap with a preceding occurrence. All length three strings occur with frequency 1/8 but the expected waiting times are 8 for TTH, 10 for THT, and 14 for TTT.

Comment: @RoyalValue I should finally get around to the crux of the question, probably: there are many ways to show what the expected value is. What tools do you have in your class? You said you already showed that the expected wait time of TTT was 14; **how** did you show that? Did you understand its solution? Where did you run into trouble applying that solution to THH?

Answer (score 1):

**Generating Function Approach**

**Duration Until $\boldsymbol{THH}$**

Any trial can uniquely be constructed from any number of $H$ atoms, then an arbitrary combination of $TH$ and $T$ atoms, then a $THH$ atom. Put this together in a generating function:
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\ \ \frac1{1-x}\ \ }^\text{$H$ atoms}\overbrace{\frac1{1-x-x^2}}^\text{$TH$, $T$ atoms}\overbrace{\quad\ x^3\quad\ \vphantom{\frac11}}^\text{$THH$ atom}
&=\frac{x^3}{1-2x+x^3}
\end{align}
$$
The expected duration is then
$$
\begin{align}
\left.x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{x^3}{1-2x+x^3}\right|_{x=\frac12}
&=\left.\frac{x^3(3-4x)}{\left(1-2x+x^3\right)^2}\right|_{x=\frac12}\\[9pt]
&=8
\end{align}
$$

---

**Duration Until $\boldsymbol{THT}$**

Any trial can be uniquely constructed from any number of $H$ atoms, then an arbitrary combination of $T$ and $TH^n$ atoms for $n\ge2$, then a $THT$ atom. Put this together in a generating function:
$$
\overbrace{\ \ \frac1{1-x}\ \ }^\text{$H$ atoms}\overbrace{\frac1{1-x-\frac{x^3}{1-x}}}^\text{$T$, $TH^n$ atoms}\overbrace{\quad\ x^3\quad\ \vphantom{\frac11}}^\text{$THT$ atom}=\frac{x^3}{1-2x+x^2-x^3}
$$
The expected duration is then
$$
\begin{align}
\left.x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{x^3}{1-2x+x^2-x^3}\right|_{x=\frac12}
&=\left.\frac{x^3\left(3-4x+x^2\right)}{\left(1-2x+x^2-x^3\right)^2}\right|_{x=\frac12}\\[9pt]
&=10
\end{align}
$$

---

**Duration Until $\boldsymbol{TTT}$**

Any trial can be uniquely constructed from any number of $H$, $TH$, and $TTH$ atoms, then an $TTT$ atom. Put this together in a generating function:
$$
\overbrace{\frac1{1-x-x^2-x^3}}^\text{$H$, $TH$, and $TTH$ atoms}\overbrace{\quad\ x^3\quad\ \vphantom{\frac11}}^\text{$TTT$ atom}=\frac{x^3}{1-x-x^2-x^3}
$$
The expected duration is then
$$
\begin{align}
\left.x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{x^3}{1-x-x^2-x^3}\right|_{x=\frac12}
&=\left.\frac{x^3\left(3-2x-x^2\right)}{\left(1-x-x^2-x^3\right)^2}\right|_{x=\frac12}\\[9pt]
&=14
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your edit is not quite right and gives the wrong answer.

For a pattern like TTH, you could consider $E[X_{TT}]$ as the expected remaining number of flips if the last two were TT,   $E[X_{TT}]$ if the last one was T but the last two were not TT, and $E[X]$ if the last was not T and the last three were not TTH.  Since you must now flip a coin and get heads or tails, you can say

- $E[X_{TT}] = 1 + \frac12 \times 0 + \frac12 \times E[X_{TT}]$
- $E[X_{T}] = 1 + \frac12 \times E[X] + \frac12 \times E[X_{TT}]$
- $E[X] = 1 + \frac12 \times E[X] + \frac12 \times E[X_{T}]$

so three equations in three unknowns.  The solutions are thus $E[X_{TT}]=2$ and $E[X_{T}]=6$ and $E[X]=8$ and you want the last of these